# Page numbers of Microsoft Word 2007 document are wrong; how can I correct them?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, page-numbers

I'm writting an article and I need to do it in a specific format. To help me with that the "staff" provided me with a template. Unfortunately the template is bugged: the first page is being counted as 101, then it increases till page 107 and then it goes back to 102 and continues growing normally again.

How can I reset the page count so that the first page will be 1 and there will be no "start again" in the middle of the document? I couldn't find anything on the web about this problem.

(I know I could simply finish my article, then copy and paste it to another document and save that, but not only it might actually bring the bug to the new article, but most importantly it would "kill" all formatting options in the "Style" section. Anyway I would prefer to correct the bug in the own document.)

Comment: Try removing all the "Section Breaks"

Comment: Or see [Continuous page numbers in Word 2007 document with section breaks](http://superuser.com/q/202151)

Comment: @DavidPostill how do I remove Section Breaks? I can only see the button fro *adding* Section Breaks.

Comment: [How to Delete a Section Break in Word 2007](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-delete-a-section-break-in-word-2007.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this in the Footer section of the page in question. Right click on the Page number that is wrong and select Format Page Numbers...  Here you can select several self evident functions with the "Holy Grail" being "Start at:[___].  This is for Word 2013.  See below for 2007.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I couldn't find the "Start at" function. When I enter in the popup there is a list of "field names" where "Page" is selected, then I'm able in a field to edit the "Codes in the field", but I can't manage to make any "Start at" to work. Note: Free translation from Word in Portuguese.

Comment: With the page number highlighted, go to the Ribbon, click the Design tab→Header & Footer→Page Number→Format Page Numbers...
Use the dialog that comes up to customize the numbering for the first section, and then click OK.
Scroll to the next section that you want to be numbered differently. On the Ribbon, go to the Design tab→Navigation and turn off Link to Previous.
Change number formatting the same way you did with the first section.
Repeat these steps for each section that needs to be customized.

Comment: thanks for the reply; now I was able to do it and everything is fine!